# Trying to launch popup window but getting Uncaught TypeError: $(…).css(…).velocity is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm new to JavaScript & JQuery obviously.. and new to this website!

I know this is going to be a silly question but can anyone figure out why I'm getting this error? I tried googling and reading up on it. I'm nearly sure its something to do with the order the js scripts are in.

The error I'm getting in the console is

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css(...).velocity is not a function
I'm using fullpage.js, modernizer and jquery The velocity script is in main.js on line 105 I've attached a link to the website to show the error, when you click the bottom of the image a popup is meant to display with more information.

http://thisisme.me/stack/simple.html

If I move the js scripts around I can get it to work but then fullscreen js or the nav bar wont work. It's meant to work like this example http://thisisme.me/stack/design.html

Thanks anyone for their help in advance.

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta name="description" content="fullPage very simple demo." />
    <meta name="keywords"  content="fullpage,jquery,demo,simple" />
    <meta name="Resource-type" content="Document" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css"> <!-- Resource style -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff']
            });
        });
    </script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->  
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="button_container" id="toggle">
  <span class="top"></span>
  <span class="middle"></span>
  <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="fullpage">

    <div class="section active" id="section0">
        <h1>fullPage.js</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <h1>fullPage.js</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
        <ul class="cd-items cd-container">
  <li class="cd-item">
    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Maisons</a>
  </li> <!-- cd-item -->

  <li class="cd-item">
    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
  </li> <!-- cd-item -->

  <li class="cd-item">
    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
  </li> <!-- cd-item -->

  <li class="cd-item">
    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
  </li> <!-- cd-item -->

  <li class="cd-item">
    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
  </li> <!-- cd-item -->

  <li class="cd-item">
    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
  </li> <!-- cd-item -->

  <li class="cd-item">
    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
  </li> <!-- cd-item -->

  <li class="cd-item">
    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
  </li> <!-- cd-item -->
   <!-- cd-item -->
</ul> <!-- cd-items -->

<div class="cd-quick-view">
  <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
    <ul class="cd-slider">
      <li class="selected"><img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Product 1"></li>
      <li><img src="img/item-2.jpg" alt="Product 2"></li>
      <li><img src="img/item-3.jpg" alt="Product 3"></li>
    </ul> <!-- cd-slider -->

    <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
      <li><a class="cd-next" href="#0">Prev</a></li>
      <li><a class="cd-prev" href="#0">Next</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- cd-slider-navigation -->
  </div> <!-- cd-slider-wrapper -->

  <div class="cd-item-info">
    <h2>Produt Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione. Numquam eveniet quo, ullam itaque expedita impedit. Eveniet, asperiores amet iste repellendus similique reiciendis, maxime laborum praesentium.</p>

    <ul class="cd-item-action">
      <li><button class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</button></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Learn more</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- cd-item-action -->
  </div> <!-- cd-item-info -->
  <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
</div> <!-- cd-quick-view -->
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3"><h1>Just the simplest demo ever</h1></div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->  
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

css
    .overlay {
      position: fixed;
      background: #FF5252;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0%;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
              transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
      overflow: hidden;

```
  opacity:    0.5;
  z-index:    10;
}
.overlay.open {
  opacity: .9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay.open li {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
          animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .35s;
          animation-delay: .35s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
          animation-delay: .4s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .45s;
          animation-delay: .45s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .50s;
          animation-delay: .50s;
}
.overlay nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}
.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: .35s;
          transition: .35s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

css2

```
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::after, *::before {
  content: '';
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #3e585f;
  background-color: #47374e;
}
body::after {
  /* dark overlay layer - visible when we fire .cd-quick-view */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(71, 55, 78, 0.8);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body.overlay-layer::after {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
    transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  }
}

a {
  color: #f82f53;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* --------------------------------

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.cd-container {
  /* this class is used to give a max-width to the element it is applied to, and center it horizontally when it reaches that max-width */
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.cd-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* --------------------------------

Main components

-------------------------------- */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 160px;
  line-height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
header h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    line-height: 180px;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-size: 1.625rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  header {
    line-height: 220px;
  }
}

.cd-items {
  padding: 1em 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-items {
    padding: 2em 0 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-items {
    padding: 4em 0 0;
  }
}

.cd-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
.cd-item > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-item {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4% 2em 0;
  }
  .cd-item:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-item {
    width: 22%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4% 2.8em 0;
  }
  .cd-item:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 4%;
  }
  .cd-item:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .cd-item.empty-box::after {
    /* box visible as placeholder when the .cd-quick-view zooms in */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #392c3f;
  }
}

.cd-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-trigger:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-trigger {
    /* always visible on small devices */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-trigger {
    /* only visible on hover on big devices */
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .no-touch .cd-item:hover .cd-trigger {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .touch .cd-item .cd-trigger {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.cd-quick-view {
  /* quick view non available on small devices */
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-quick-view {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 900px;
    visibility: hidden;
    /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: left, top, width;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .cd-quick-view:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  .cd-quick-view.is-visible {
    /* class added when user clicks on .cd-trigger */
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .cd-quick-view.animate-width {
    /* class added at the end of the first zoom-in animation */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  }
}

.cd-slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.cd-slider-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cd-slider {
  float: left;
}
.cd-slider li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.cd-slider li img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.cd-slider li.selected {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.add-content .cd-slider {
  margin-right: 3em;
}

.cd-slider-navigation {
  opacity: 0;
}
.add-content .cd-slider-navigation {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cd-slider-navigation li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 3;
}
.cd-slider-navigation li:first-child {
  left: 0;
}
.cd-slider-navigation li:last-child {
  /* equal to the .cd-slider-wrapper margin-right */
  right: 3em;
}
.cd-slider-navigation li a {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s, background 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s, background 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}
.cd-slider-navigation li a::before, .cd-slider-navigation li a::after {
  /* create arrows in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 3px;
  width: 12px;
}
.cd-slider-navigation li a::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-slider-navigation li a::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(7px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.add-content .cd-slider-navigation li a {
  opacity: .2;
}
.no-touch .cd-slider-navigation li a:hover {
  background: rgba(71, 55, 78, 0.8);
  opacity: 1;
}
.touch .cd-slider-navigation li a {
  opacity: 1;
}
.cd-slider-navigation li:first-child a::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.cd-slider-navigation li:first-child a::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
}

.cd-item-info {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3em 3em 3em 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s, visibility 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s, visibility 0s;
  transition: opacity .3s, visibility 0s;
}
.cd-item-info h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}
.cd-item-info p {
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 1em 0;
  color: #67919c;
}
.cd-item-info .cd-item-action li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.cd-item-info .cd-item-action li:first-child {
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.cd-item-info .add-to-cart {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  border: none;
  padding: .6em 1.2em;
  background-color: #f82f53;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.add-content .cd-item-info {
  /* class added at the end of the width animation, used to show the content */
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.add-content .cd-item-info h2 {
  -webkit-animation: cd-slide-in 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-slide-in 0.3s;
  animation: cd-slide-in 0.3s;
}
.add-content .cd-item-info p {
  -webkit-animation: cd-slide-in 0.4s;
  -moz-animation: cd-slide-in 0.4s;
  animation: cd-slide-in 0.4s;
}
.add-content .cd-item-info .cd-item-action {
  -webkit-animation: cd-slide-in 0.5s;
  -moz-animation: cd-slide-in 0.5s;
  animation: cd-slide-in 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-slide-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-slide-in {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-slide-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.cd-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  /* image replacement */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: transform .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
.cd-close::before, .cd-close::after {
  /* close icon in css */
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #47374e;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-close:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.add-content .cd-close {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: transform .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
```

main.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //final width --> this is the quick view image slider width
    //maxQuickWidth --> this is the max-width of the quick-view panel
    var sliderFinalWidth = 400,
        maxQuickWidth = 900;

    //open the quick view panel
    $('.cd-trigger').on('click', function(event){
        var selectedImage = $(this).parent('.cd-item').children('img'),
            slectedImageUrl = selectedImage.attr('src');

        $('body').addClass('overlay-layer');
        animateQuickView(selectedImage, sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth, 'open');

        //update the visible slider image in the quick view panel
        //you don't need to implement/use the updateQuickView if retrieving the quick view data with ajax
        updateQuickView(slectedImageUrl);
    });

    //close the quick view panel
    $('body').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-close') || $(event.target).is('body.overlay-layer')) {
            closeQuickView( sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
        }
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        //check if user has pressed 'Esc'
        if(event.which=='27'){
            closeQuickView( sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
        }
    });

    //quick view slider implementation
    $('.cd-quick-view').on('click', '.cd-slider-navigation a', function(){
        updateSlider($(this));
    });

    //center quick-view on window resize
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if($('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('is-visible')){
            window.requestAnimationFrame(resizeQuickView);
        }
    });

    function updateSlider(navigation) {
        var sliderConatiner = navigation.parents('.cd-slider-wrapper').find('.cd-slider'),
            activeSlider = sliderConatiner.children('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        if ( navigation.hasClass('cd-next') ) {
            ( !activeSlider.is(':last-child') ) ? activeSlider.next().addClass('selected') : sliderConatiner.children('li').eq(0).addClass('selected'); 
        } else {
            ( !activeSlider.is(':first-child') ) ? activeSlider.prev().addClass('selected') : sliderConatiner.children('li').last().addClass('selected');
        } 
    }

    function updateQuickView(url) {
        $('.cd-quick-view .cd-slider li').removeClass('selected').find('img[src="'+ url +'"]').parent('li').addClass('selected');
    }

    function resizeQuickView() {
        var quickViewLeft = ($(window).width() - $('.cd-quick-view').width())/2,
            quickViewTop = ($(window).height() - $('.cd-quick-view').height())/2;
        $('.cd-quick-view').css({
            "top": quickViewTop,
            "left": quickViewLeft,
        });
    } 

    function closeQuickView(finalWidth, maxQuickWidth) {
        var close = $('.cd-close'),
            activeSliderUrl = close.siblings('.cd-slider-wrapper').find('.selected img').attr('src'),
            selectedImage = $('.empty-box').find('img');
        //update the image in the gallery
        if( !$('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('velocity-animating') && $('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('add-content')) {
            selectedImage.attr('src', activeSliderUrl);
            animateQuickView(selectedImage, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth, 'close');
        } else {
            closeNoAnimation(selectedImage, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
        }
    }

    function animateQuickView(image, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth, animationType) {
        //store some image data (width, top position, ...)
        //store window data to calculate quick view panel position
        var parentListItem = image.parent('.cd-item'),
            topSelected = image.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
            leftSelected = image.offset().left,
            widthSelected = image.width(),
            heightSelected = image.height(),
            windowWidth = $(window).width(),
            windowHeight = $(window).height(),
            finalLeft = (windowWidth - finalWidth)/2,
            finalHeight = finalWidth * heightSelected/widthSelected,
            finalTop = (windowHeight - finalHeight)/2,
            quickViewWidth = ( windowWidth * .8 < maxQuickWidth ) ? windowWidth * .8 : maxQuickWidth ,
            quickViewLeft = (windowWidth - quickViewWidth)/2;

        if( animationType == 'open') {
            //hide the image in the gallery
            parentListItem.addClass('empty-box');
            //place the quick view over the image gallery and give it the dimension of the gallery image
            $('.cd-quick-view').css({
                "top": topSelected,
                "left": leftSelected,
                "width": widthSelected,
            }).velocity({
                //animate the quick view: animate its width and center it in the viewport
                //during this animation, only the slider image is visible
                'top': finalTop+ 'px',
                'left': finalLeft+'px',
                'width': finalWidth+'px',
            }, 1000, [ 400, 20 ], function(){
                //animate the quick view: animate its width to the final value
                $('.cd-quick-view').addClass('animate-width').velocity({
                    'left': quickViewLeft+'px',
                    'width': quickViewWidth+'px',
                }, 300, 'ease' ,function(){
                    //show quick view content
                    $('.cd-quick-view').addClass('add-content');
                });
            }).addClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            //close the quick view reverting the animation
            $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('add-content').velocity({
                'top': finalTop+ 'px',
                'left': finalLeft+'px',
                'width': finalWidth+'px',
            }, 300, 'ease', function(){
                $('body').removeClass('overlay-layer');
                $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('animate-width').velocity({
                    "top": topSelected,
                    "left": leftSelected,
                    "width": widthSelected,
                }, 500, 'ease', function(){
                    $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('is-visible');
                    parentListItem.removeClass('empty-box');
                });
            });
        }
    }
    function closeNoAnimation(image, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth) {
        var parentListItem = image.parent('.cd-item'),
            topSelected = image.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
            leftSelected = image.offset().left,
            widthSelected = image.width();

        //close the quick view reverting the animation
        $('body').removeClass('overlay-layer');
        parentListItem.removeClass('empty-box');
        $('.cd-quick-view').velocity("stop").removeClass('add-content animate-width is-visible').css({
            "top": topSelected,
            "left": leftSelected,
            "width": widthSelected,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: you didn't load velocity plugin.

Comment: Well spotted.. so the error is now gone. But I'm still getting no pop up. It's meant to work like this http://shaneogrady.me/stack/design.html

Comment: You're including `modernizr.js` and `script.js` twice, once in the `<head>` and once after `</body>` (which is an invalid location - it should be before the `</body>` tag).

Comment: @Nerdwood Thank you. I can it pop up now but please see updated script. It is now popping up but why is it displaying at the top of the page and not the section where the boxes are? http://shaneogrady.me/stack/simple.html

Comment: It's displaying at the top of the page because of the `position: fixed;` on `.cd-quick-view`. You can change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` for `.cd-quick-view` and then add `position: relative` to `.section`